# show an item from editext to spinner and save to db

Tags: android, database, android-edittext, spinner

I want to show an item from editext to spinner and save to db... how to store item in the db...

### my code :

spinner populating

```
final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();

Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

AdapterCountries = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
AdapterCountries.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spin.setAdapter(AdapterCountries);



Cursor cursor = db.getAllTitles1();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
results=cursor.getString(2);
AdapterCountries.add(results);
}
db.close();
```

and

```
 Button d_ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.d_ok);
 final EditText filename=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.filename);
 d_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //
 }});
```

any one can help me with example

Thank you...

Comment: You want to add the values entered in Edit Text into the spinner and to Database right?

Comment: Do you mean insert values entered in EditText into Database then present them in Spinner? Or insert them in EditText in Spinner and present after acceptation in Spinner and store in Database?

Comment: @dziobas any one i need to show the item from edittext to spinner... the same that has to add in the database.... thank you... guide me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have one already, then I really think you should have a SQL helper class extending the given SQLiteOpenHelper Android class. It really simplifies DB operations. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

It's **heavily** recommended.

If you set up the helper class and the instance of that class is set up like `SQLHelper sql = new SQLHelper(this);` then modifying the database is fairly simple. You should set up a method that you call from your buttons onClickListener (and possibly run it in an AsyncTask or a background thread):

```
private void addFileName(final String filename) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = sql.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(yourKeyHere, filename);
    db.insert(yourDBNameHere, null, values);
}
```

And then call the method and add it to your adapter from the listener:

```
d_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addFileName(filename.getText().toString();
        AdapterCountries.add(filename);
    }
});
```

Comment: error in the line of " SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();"

Comment: @nothing Pretty sure there isn't? `sql` should already be clarified as an instance of your SQL Helper class, otherwise it won't work. Read the full post.